# Plotting & Solving

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot replicate a graph from one of the articles and it has series of equations it has solved.

here is my code so far:

```
Tan [o] == 2 Cot[B]*(M^2*Sin[B]*Sin[B] - 1)/(M^2*(1.4 + Cos[2 B]) + 2); 

Pr1[o_, M_] := 1 + 2*1.4/2.4*(M^2*Sin[B]*Sin[B] - 1)
Plot[Table[Pr1[o, M], {o, {10*Pi/180}}] // Evaluate, {M, 1, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

The variables `o`, `B` and `M` are related to the tangent expression. After that I'm trying to solve the next equation and plot that with certain value of `o` and as `M` varies from 1 to 3. For some reason, I'm not getting any error but my graph isn't showing up at all.

Also note that the tan expression produces 6 roots for given `M` and `o`, I want to only take the lowest positive value out of the 6 roots.

---

#### Edit

Here is my new code. I used the 4th root instead of 1st one. Thank to belisarius for helping out:

```
s = Solve[Tan[o] == 2 Cot[B]*(M^2*Sin[B]*Sin[B] - 1)/(M^2*(1.4 + Cos[2 B]) + 2), {B}];

Pr1[o_, M_] := 1 + 2*1.4/2.4*(M^2*Sin[B]*Sin[B] - 1)
Plot[Table[Evaluate[Pr1[o, M] /. s[[4]]], {o, {10*Pi/180}}], {M, 1, 3}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

The plot shows a step near the value of ~1.4 of M. I want to eliminate this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can either take the region after that point with the option `PlotRange -> {{1.425, 3}, All}` or exclude that region with the option `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, (x > 1.425)]`.

Comment: For Information: Using single capital letters for variable names is discouraged as they often conflict with built in functions, i.e. `D`, `N`.

Answer (score 1):

A kickstart:

```
s = Solve[ Tan[o] == 2 Cot[B]*(M^2*Sin[B]*Sin[B] - 1)/(M^2*(1.4 + Cos[2 B]) + 2), {B}];

Pr1[o_, M_] := 1 + 2*1.4/2.4*(M^2*Sin[B] - 1)
Plot[Table[Pr1[o, M] /. s[[1]], {o, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/4}], {M, 1, 3}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

You have to be careful about what solutions you use from `s`

Comment: Thank you! I just realized I made few corrections which are edited in the question now. I'm using the 4th root which is the first positive one. Also, the new graph has a sort of a step function before M = 1.4, any way for me to eliminate from the graph?

Comment: Why use bot `Evaluate` and `Evaluated -> True`?

Comment: @m_goldberg I was trying both and forgot to remove one of them when posting. Thanks.